# Reverse of \only

Tags: beamer

Is there a command which is the reverse of `\only`?

E.g. if I want to strike out something in a table I want to strike out one cell in slide three like so:

```
... & \only<3->{Data}\reverseofonly<3->{\sout{Data}} & ...
```

I have tried with `\invisible`, but it reserves space, thus widening my table column since it has to reserve space for the striked out "Data" prior to slide 3.

Comment: I think you are after `\alt`: have a look on the manual for examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For details, see [beameruserguide.pdf, p. 86, paragraph `\renewcommand<>`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ulem}

\renewcommand<>\sout[1]{\alt#2{\beameroriginal\sout{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\sout<1>{Striked on 1st slide}
\sout{Striked always}
\sout<2->{Striked on 2nd slide}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can simulate the same effect by using `\alt` directly, but it gets annoying:

```
\begin{frame}

\alt<1>{\sout{Striked on 1st slide}}{Striked on 1st slide}
\sout{Striked always}
\alt<2->{\sout{Striked on 2nd slide}}{Striked on 2nd slide}

\end{frame}
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by **Andrew Stacey**, you can use directly

```
\only<2->{\sout}{Striked on 2nd slide}`
```

However, I don't like this notation myself: the text is not a 2nd parameter of `\only`, it's a 1st parameter of `\sout`.

Comment: Though you could do `\only<2>{\sout}{Stricken on 2nd slide}`

Comment: @AndrewStacey Well, you're right, edited.

Comment: @tohecz Used your initial solution, but forgot to mark it as solved. Thanks.