# optional <⟨overlay specification⟩>'s for macros

Tags: beamer

In the `beamer` documentation you can find macros that have two `<⟨overlay specification⟩>`'s. For example:

```
\alt<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨default text⟩}{⟨alternative text⟩}<⟨overlay specification⟩>
```

However, I couldn't find an explanation what is the difference? It seems like it is only possible to use one `<(overlay specification)>`. Is it some backwards compatibility issue? In the following MWE seems I could not spot the difference:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Foo
  \item \alt<2>{Hello}{World}
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Bar}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Foo
  \item \alt{Hello}{World}<2>
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So what is the deal here?

Comment: Not sure at all, but I think this design choice allows more flexibility at user side to set overlay specifications.

Comment: Probably only Till can answer this! Reading the code, I suspect you are right on the 'back compatibility' idea, but there are no comments.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Can you elaborate? If the result is the same then where is the flexibility?

Comment: I mean that according to personal programming style, somebody `\alt<>{}{}` while others might prefer `\alt{}{}<>`. Allowing both versions provides a choice to users.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I don't think that's a particularly _good_ interface choice!

Comment: @JosephWright: why not?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino LaTeX (at the kernel level) is all about trying to provide a consistent interface. All of the `bemear` docs show that it extends standard LaTeX syntax by adding the `<...>` arg as the _first_ optional argument to commands. So adding it at the end as well is not good.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it correctly, it's for ease of your job. The natural place for an optional argument is is of course before all the other arguments:

```
\alt<2>{this}{that}
```

However, imagine you define a macro with overlays to be specified when used, then you can do:

```
\newcommand\macro{\alt{this}{that}}
...
\macro<2>
```

Of course, there's another (maybe more proper) way how to achieve this, cf. [beameruserguide.pdf, p. 86, paragraph `\renewcommand<>`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) and [Reverse of `\only`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155754):

```
\newcommand<>\macro{\alt#1{this}{that}}
...
\macro<2>
```

But it's a matter of taste which one do you prefer. I find optional arguments after mandatory ones strange, so I certainly use the latter option.